# Проблема с соединением Putty

Tags: putty, connection

Установил Putty, полностью также как и другу, конфигурация идентична. При попытке соединиться по адресу, появляется консоль на секунду, а потом сама закрывается без каких либо ошибок, раньше все работало нормально но в какой-то момент начались проблемы